Wordpres redux not renaming existing page using change_arguments
I have a Wordpress theme which uses Redux framework 3.6 .. The theme author has created a page and has a menu on the left hand side of the admin screen at the bottom. All i want to do is rename the menu item and page name, but despite trying the different filters listed here https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/blob/master/sample/sample-config.php nothing at all seems to work, after I add my code to my child themes functions.php file, do i need to do anything for it to reload? just reloading the page doesnt do anything. My code is very simple, i have placed it at the bottom of the functions.php file in my child theme;
$opt_name = "redux_demo";

if ( ! function_exists( 'change_arguments' ) ) {
    function change_arguments( array $args ): array {
        $args['menu_title'] = 'Mine Options';
        $args['page_title'] = 'Mine Options';

        return $args;
    }
}

add_filter('redux/options/' . $opt_name . '/args', 'change_arguments');

I have opened the existing panel, opened the console and typed redux.args.opt_name and it returns 'redux_demo' so i think i have everything right, i just cant seem to get it to go.

if ( ! function_exists( 'change_arguments' ) ) - and you have verified that condition isn't perhaps false already?

@CBroe .. Sorry about the newb question, but how would i test that

Add some basic debug output using var_dump for example; or simply remove the if wrapper (if a function by that name already exists at this point, you would get a fatal error saying that you can't re-declare it.)

Ahhh @CBroe .... I am now getting the following ; Cannot redeclare change_arguments() (previously declared in ........redux-framework-master/sample/sample-config.php:680) .. Is there a way around this so i can actually use the functionality?

Just give your function a different name - the naming is completely up to you, you just need to modify the second parameter of your add_filter call accordingly as well.
